# How to read values from properties file in ExtJs

Tags: javascript, extjs, properties-file

I want to read values from `config.properties` and use these values in my `ExtJs ComboBox`. I do not want to read from JSON file.

Where should I place the `config.properties` file? Should I place it in the webcontent directly? I do not want to hard code the path/ or at least reduce it.

And how can I access property values through JavaScript.?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is not ExtJS specific but in general rather applicable to javascript as a whole.

Best bet would be to either include it in a global file that gets included in your app and is namespaced appropriately to your app so as to minimise chance of collisions with any other potential variables

```js
MyApp = {
    config:{
        property1:'something',
        property2:'something2'
      }
  }


// Then you can access this anywhere you like 

myProperty1 = MyApp.config.property1; // assigns the string "something" to variable myProperty1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can load the properties file into a data store, this way you can have the key-value pairs in the your properties file mapped to a simple model with fields 
key and value. 
And to enable your proxy to load data from the properties file and be converted into the corresponding model you'll have to create a reader that'll read the data from the properties file and convert to the desired record.

This custom package for [i18n](https://github.com/elmasse/Ext.i18n.Bundle/tree/master/src/i18n) will give you some idea how to do that.